# Mapping domain name to free PAAS web hosting cloud URL

Tags: dns, paas

Several companies offer a PAAS web hosting services for free, e.g. Amazon, google, cloudbees.
When you use their service they assign a URL to accessing your app.
If you use Google App Engine, for example, you are told the URL to access your app is something like   http://your_app_id.appspot.com

If I own domain name, say myxyz.com, is it possible to somehow map this domain to the assigned Google App Engine URL?
So for example a request such as:  http://myxyz.com/myApp?a=3
would also be forwarded to: http://your_app_id.appspot.com/myApp?a=3
but i'd like the user to still see, in the browser address field, the myxyz.com URL?
assuming it's possible, which company should one approach to perform this mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found information about this. the answer is Yes. the PASS company provides the means to do that as specified here for example: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain